# Button load more not loading, in react typescript & fakeApi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

can anybody tell me please why button load more doesn't work. I wrote down the function load more in the file hooks. Then I gave function throw the props. As a result it doesn't work.
It returns the same data. how to improve it . Here is a fetching:

```js
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://fakestoreapi.com/",
})

export const getProducts = async ( page=1, limit = 5) => {
    const {data} = await instance.get<IProduct[]>("products", {
        params: {
        page,
            limit
        }
    });
    return data; 
}
```

```
function Product() {
   const [products, setProducts] = useState<IProduct[]>([]);
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(1);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchProducts = async () => {
        try {
        setLoading(true)
        setError(' ')
              const data = await getProducts(page);
              setProducts(data);
              setLoading(false)
            } catch (error: unknown) {
              setLoading(false)
              setError("Network Error!")
            }
        }

        fetchProducts()
    }, [page]);

  const loadMore = () => {
     setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1)
    };

  return (<>
    <ul className={s.wrap}>
        {loading && <p>...loading</p>}
        {error && <ErrorMessage error={ error} />}
        {products.map(product => <ProductList product={product} key={product.id} />)}
        {!loading && products.length >= 3 && <button  onClick={loadMore}>Load more</button>}
        </ul>
    </>
      
  )
}

export default Product
```

Comment: What is happening instead?

Comment: The page is loading, but new cards don't appear, there are no errors in console

Comment: Probably `await getProducts(page)` returns the same data

Comment: Yes, it returns the same data. how to improve it . Here is a fetching: 
...

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://fakestoreapi.com/",
})

export const getProducts = async ( page=1, limit = 5) => {
    const {data} = await instance.get<IProduct[]>("products", {
        params: {
        page,
            limit
        }
    });
    return data; 
}


thanks

Comment: Edit your question instead of putting code in the comment

Comment: Your backend probably ignores the `page` parameter

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the code, I'm new here :)

Comment: I have removed the page, but didn't help:( It  stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code doesn't have any problem.

The problem is that the fake store api doesn't have a 'page' parameter, only has 'limit' and 'sort' parameters.

For getting your required result using this api, you need to update your getProducts function.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, can you give a green check mark to my answer?